# In old C, what does this mean? double (*Window)(double)

Tags: java, c

I am trying to convert some old DSP code written in C into Java and later to C#.  I do not understand what the argument "double (*Window)(double)" means and how to reference it in the Java code.  The following function has me unsure what to do.

```
void WinFirI(float LowOmega, float UppOmega,
       float *Shape, int Len, double (*Window)(double), float shift)
{ int i; double time,phase,shape;
// printf("WinFirI: %5.3f %5.3f %d\n",LowOmega,UppOmega,Len);
  for(i=0; i<Len; i++)
  { time=i+(1.0-shift)-(float)Len/2; phase=2*M_PI*time/Len;
    if(time==0) shape=UppOmega-LowOmega;
       else shape=(sin(UppOmega*time)-sin(LowOmega*time))/time;
// printf("%2d %5.1f %5.2f %7.4f %7.4f\n",i,time,phase,shape,(*Window)     (phase));
    Shape[i]=shape*(*Window)(phase)/M_PI; }
}
```

So far I have written this:

```
public void WinFirI(float LowOmega, float UppOmega,
       float[] Shape, int Len, double[] Window, float shift) {
        double time;
        double phase;
        double shape;
//      printf("WinFirI: %5.3f %5.3f %d\n",LowOmega,UppOmega,Len);
        for(int i=0; i<Len; i++) {
            time = i +(1.0-shift) - (float)Len/2;
            phase = 2 * Math.PI * time / Len;
            if(time==0) {
                shape = UppOmega - LowOmega;
            }
       else {
                shape=(Math.sin(UppOmega*time) - Math.sin(LowOmega*time))    / time;
            }
//          printf("%2d %5.1f %5.2f %7.4f %7.4f\n",i,time,phase,shape,    (*Window)(phase));
            //Shape[i]=shape*(*Window)(phase)/M_PI; 
            Shape[i] = shape * Window[phase]/Math.PI;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a function pointer argument. The function receives one `double` as argument and returns a `double`. You invoke it this way: `Window(0.0);`.

Comment: Why the tag spam?

Comment: Why old ? you mean the C is old ? or this is old in C ?

Comment: Read the tag wikis. The C tag implies standard C which is C11 from 2011. Not really "old". If you mean a previous version or pre-ISO C, use the appropriate tag.

Comment: Why old?  Because I think it was originally written in 1990 by Pawel Jalocha.  Then someone incorporated it into an Android MT63 program available at github.  I find it relatively easier to follow than the FLDIGI open source program (great product, but a giant headache trying to figure out the FLDIGI code).  Strange that there is no MT63 specification, only C code to look at.  And the Android developer kept it in C - apparently didn't want to convert it to Java to match the rest of his project.  Except for some possible minor changes made by the Android developer, this C code is 17 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an added note, implementing this function pointer behavior in Java would be done through an anonymous class/interface.

```
double Window(double param);
```

In Java would be:

```
interface WindowFnWrapper {
    double Window(double param);
}
```

Then the function signature would be:

```
public void WinFirI(float LowOmega, float UppOmega,
   float[] Shape, int Len, WindowFnWrapper WindowWrapper, float shift)
```

Every time you call `Window()` you would replace it with `WindowWrapper.Window()`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work - well at least compiler is happy.  I have many thousands of lines of code to convert.  I think it's really crazy to have an argument which is a function.  But that's what the original author did many many years ago in C.  I prefer to keep things simple.

Comment: @howard a recommendation. Don't try to directly port C to Java. What makes a great C program is often going to fly in the face of Java best practices. You can beat it into working, but you'll likely wind up with inferior Java code.

Comment: @Howard-- passing function pointers as arguments is extremely common in C; for example, that is how different comparison functions can be given to `qsort()`.

Comment: Very early in my career, I came to value code that is easy to understand.  That is why I like Java (and C#). Many features in C/C++ that can make things obscure, complicated syntax, features that one can hang oneself to death (pointers) were purposely omitted from Java.  Coming from a real-time background, I also like to avoid packages I have no control over.  I often avoided certain features in languages because they had memory leaks and over the weeks the programs would grow in virtual size to the point of slowing down/paging.  Point is what I like is probably unique due to my background.

Comment: Felix.  Sorry to bother you again.  How would I now pass a function.  For example "double Blackman3(double phase)" ?  How can I pass this function?  You example is for the function receiving the wrapper, and how it will execute the wrapper's function.  But how do I pass a function to it during a function call?

Comment: Is this correct?                              public class Blackman3 implements WindowFnWrapper {
        public double Window(double phase) { // from the Motorola BBS
            double result = 0.35875 + 0.48829*Math.cos(phase) +
                        0.14128*Math.cos(2*phase) + 0.01168*Math.cos(3*phase);
            return result;
        } 
    }                                            And in calling program.          private MT63DSP.WindowFnWrapper Blackman3 = dsp.new Blackman3();       and then      just use Blackman3 in the parameter list when passing the function?

Comment: Yes, if the receiving function accepts `WindowFnWrapper` as a parameter then `Blackman3` will go through.

Answer (score 6):

Pointer to function with parameter double returning double.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `double (*Window)(double)` declares a parameter `Window`, whose value is a pointer to a function.  That function must be one which takes a single `double` as an argument, and returns a `double`.

In your C code, (well, actually the commented-out part), that pointer gets dereferenced, and the function called, passing `phase` as its argument.  That is, the value of the expression `(*Window) (phase)` is just the result of calling the function whose address you passed in.

If you're using Java 8 or above, the nearest available equivalent is the `Function` generic class, from the `java.util.function` package.  So if you write

```
import java.util.function.Function;
```

then you can declare the parameter as

```
Function<Double,Double> window
```

and use it as

```
window.apply(phase);
```

The only real difference between this and your C code is that the type parameters to Java generics can't be primitive types such as `double`.

`Double` is a reference type that works a bit like `double`, except that a `Double` can be null, whereas a `double` can't.  In effect, this should make no difference to your code, except that you may want to add some error handling to deal with the case where `window.apply(phase)` evaluates to null.